# An HTML Input Field I Fail to Reset via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I do not use jQuery, unless this will force me.

My apparently simple HTML document has a div with 3 inputs, the 3rd of which, for some reason, I fail to reset. My cleaned-up-for-display code appears below:

```
<div>
 <label>LIMIT 1
  <select id="limit1"> 
   <option value="1">Choice1</option>
   <option value="2">Choice2</option>
  </select>
 </label>
 <label>LIMIT 2
  <select id="limit2">
   <option value="1">Choice1</option>
   <option value="2">Choice2</option>
  </select>
 </label>

 <label>ENTER A VALUE
  <input type="text" id=“parm2” value="20" size="3" maxlength="4">
 </label>
</div>
```

Here’s my validation and reset code:

```
var limit1 = document.getElementById("limit1");
var limit2 = document.getElementById("limit2");
if (limit2.value < limit1.value) {
 alert("ERROR: 1st must be less than 2nd");
 limit1.value = 1; 
 limit2.value = 2;
 return false;
}  // Above resets of select options works!
var uValue = document.getElementById(“parm2”).value;
if (isNaN(uValue)) {
 uValue.value = "20";   // This reset fails!
 return false;
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
var uValue = document.getElementById(“parm2”).value;
```

selects the *value* of the element, not the element. so "123".value doesn't really make sense, store the element if you want to reset its value.

```
var uElement = document.getElementById('parm2');
// later on
uElement.value = 20;
```

Side Note: property access *usually* isn't expensive, so storing *just* the element and accessing the value with .value later on is perfectly acceptable instead of using two variables.

Comment: `$('#beard').grow();` wasn't working so I had to GIMP it.

Comment: @ruffy did you ever solve your issue? If so please update us and/or accept an answer.

Comment: My problem was as BOTH RESPONDERS pointed out, namely, that I had accessed only a value - instead of a node. AFTER I have identified the node, THAT's when I can alter its value. In my original question, I had the 3rd pegged wrong; I should have accesses it like I did the former two. Now that it was pointed out to me, I was embarrassed in hindsight, for now it's obvious. I have checked on both RESPONDERS' up arrows, but only one of them "takes" - but I want to thank BOTH RESPONDERS.

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing `.value` twice

```
var parm2 = document.getElementById(“parm2”);
if (isNaN(parm2.value)) {
 parm2.value = "20";   // This reset no longer fails!
 return false;
}
```

Comment: might be more useful to explain the changes you've made for the OP.

Comment: Thanks tcigrand. (What's OP stand for?)

Comment: Original Poster. aka, you.